# Incorrect Cookie Values, while reading it.

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have a webforms app that uses cookies to store some temp data so that i can read it further on to do some other functions.
here is the code for setting/writing a cookie.

```
  Response.Cookies["Region"].Value = Convert.ToString(DropDownList1.SelectedItem);
                    Response.Cookies["Region"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(100);

                    HttpCookie dxs = new HttpCookie("Region");//cookie name
                    dxs.Values["Region"] = Convert.ToString(DropDownList1.SelectedItem);                     
                    dxs.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(100);

                    Response.Cookies.Add(dxs);                       
                    Response.Cookies["Region"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(100);
                    Response.Redirect("~/HomePage.aspx");
```

here i how i read the cookie

```
if (Request.Cookies["Region"] != null)//read cookie
            {
                HttpCookie aCookie = Request.Cookies["Region"];
                ab = Server.HtmlEncode(aCookie.Value);
            }
            else 
            {
                return;
            }
```

Now, here lies my problem, while reading, the cookie it gives values like Region=xyz or Region=abc; attached image.
[image: Incorrect Cookie]

What am i doing wrong?

Any and all help is appreciated..

Comment: IIRC the request and response cookie collections are entirely different so if you add to the response and try and read it from the request in the same web request it wont exist in the request collection yet....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dxs.Values - Gets a collection of key/value pairs that are contained within a single cookie. 

You are giving the name of this cookies as Region.

And in side this cookie, you are storing a collection of one item - key=Region and value=Goa.

if you want to create a cookie with name as Region, and value as Goa, you can try like -

```
HttpCookie dxs = new HttpCookie("Region", Convert.ToString(DropDownList1.SelectedItem));
```

and add this cookie to your Resopnse cookies collection -

```
Response.Cookies.Add(dxs);
```